# How to parse a file given its specific structure

Tags: grep

I need to parse a .fasta file (big data) or you may think of a .txt file which has a particular structure. For that aim I want to use linux. I would like to read the file "line by line". By line I do not mean every line, rather particular lines that recurrently appear in the text following a specific pattern. The striking pattern is the symbol `>`. The lines that I want to read are the ones that are situated between lines containing that symbol. Unfortunately, the needed lines occupy two lines. I am not experienced in linux. So, I need some help. The ultimate goal is either to redirect the needed lines into a new file or to simply read them. Many thanks for any suggestion of code. A few lines of the text look like this:

```
>ERR194147.15240306 HSQ1004:134:C0D8DACXX:1:1204:4727:27246/1
AGCCATTTTCCAGATGAGAAAGTCAAGGTTTGGAGAGAGATTCTGTGCCTTTGAGCAGGCTTGGGGGTCTGTAAGAAGCA
GGGCCACAGTTCAAACCTAG
>ERR194147.15950974 HSQ1004:134:C0D8DACXX:2:1307:21234:48802/1
ATGCATACTTCATGCACCCCAGCCCCCGTGGGCAGCTATTGGGTTTGCTATCTAATCTCTTTCTCCACCAGCTACCCTTC
TTTATCAACTTATATGTTTA
```

Comment: It's not so much how do you read the lines but more about what you want to do with them. Do I hear you want all lines except those starting with `>` saved to another file?

Comment: Yes. That's true. I want nevertheless to have the DNA string on a single line and not on two lines as shown in the file.

Comment: I don't know what that means. What's a DNA string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab lines that match a pattern with the `grep` tool. See `man grep` for details

```
grep -v '^>' source_file > output_file
```

This uses a Regular Expression (RE) to match `>` at the start (`^`) of a line. The `-v` option inverts the match so only non-matching lines are output. Finally `> output_file` is a standard shell construct to send the output to the named file

Comment: Many thanks. Since I need to do this on thousands of such strings, should one rather use a loop inside a shell script and then use instead of ">"  rather ">>" so as to avoid overwriting, right ?

Comment: Why would you want to loop? Lots of input files and one output file is almost the same command as I've given you already